# Pad and increase image area to fit dilation output | opencv | python

Tags: image-processing, opencv, mathematical-morphology, dilation, python

I am applying image dilation using opencv-python.

This is the input image,

[image]

After, applying dilation, the output is as follows,

[image]

The dilated image is getting clipped by the edges of image. How can we increase the area of the output image automatically to fit the output of the dilation operation.

Comment: Create a larger image (margin equal to the dilation half-size), copy the original image in the middle and fill the margin with black.

Comment: opencv has `copyMakeBorder`, no need to mess around